# List all CSV files from Dropbox in iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

In my app, I am integrating the drop box. For this, I want to display the all csv files which are in any folder.

Right Now, I did like: The csv files which are only in app folder are displayed.

```
[[self restClient] loadMetadata:@"/"];

#pragma mark DBRestClientDelegate methods

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    NSArray* validExtensions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"csv",nil];
    NSMutableArray* newPhotoPaths = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (DBMetadata* child in metadata.contents) {
        NSString* extension = [[child.path pathExtension] lowercaseString];
        if (!child.isDirectory && [validExtensions indexOfObject:extension] != NSNotFound) {

            // [files addObject:[child.path lastPathComponent]];
            [files addObject:child.path];
            [newPhotoPaths addObject:child.path];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",files);
    [tbl reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Dropbox apps have a setting which allows them to I my a

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox apps have a setting which allows them to only access the app folder OR have access to the users entire Dropbox. Change this setting from the API page and it should work

Comment: Besides that, you might want to use search API ``[[self restClient] searchPath:@"/" forKeyword:@".csv"];`` instead of manually filtering the metadata. It's simpler and you also get cdv files in sub-folders.